# Need help correcting (deliberately faulty) equation code

Tags: math-mode, equations

For a test, I need to edit and correct the following equation, which I understand to contain several syntax errors.

```
5\square{3X}+2X**2-\frac{3X/2}*
```

Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with LaTeX syntax.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please do not add email adresses in your question! Be aware of spammers! And please make your homework by yourself!

Comment: What is `2X**2` meant to be? A power of 2? That's not the way of typing it in TeX however

Comment: I’m applying for a proofreading job specializing in manufacturing content. This is a question in the job application, with mandatory entry.  They are asking me to edit the incorrect expression; I have no experience in doing this and am looking for help.

Comment: The question is very vague, but, as I understand it, the equation is incorrectly expressed in LaTeX guidelines.  Might be bracket placement, spaces, use of ampersand;  I just don’t know.  Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying your (typesetting) objective.

I spottted (at least) six [6!!] mistakes in the code fragment you posted:

- The macro `\square` is non-standard. Instead of `\square{...}`, just write `(...)^2`.
- Use of `{` and `}` to denote the scope of the squaring operations. Use `(` and `)` instead.
- Use of `**` instead of `^` to denote exponentiation.
- The `\frac` macro takes two arguments, not one. Thus, don't write `\frac{3X/2}`. Instead, write `\frac{3X}{2}`.
- The final `*` (asterisk) symbol seems entirely misplaced.
- Last but not least, one needs to initiate and terminate math mode explicitily, e.g., via `$` directives.

With some misgivings -- after all, still further errors might be lurking somewhere -- I'd write

```
$5(3X)^2+2X^2-\frac{3X}{2}$
```

Maybe, just maybe, the `\square` macro was defined via an instruction such as `\newcommand\square[1]{(#1)^2}`. If that's the case -- you better verify that it is -- you could write

```
$5\square{3X}+2X^2-\frac{3X}{2}$
```

However, I can't see the point of bothering defining a macro called `\square`.

Comment: Thank you!  I submitted it as the answer.  Still don’t get how it relates to proofreading manufacturing documents.